# Fortran line continuations with function or subroutine calls

Tags: fortran

I tried to continue a line with a call a function call using the `&` method, but I get an error that appears to be due to the compiler interpreting it as a parameter itself.

```
something = mrfuntion(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3 &
                      parameter4)
```

Is there a way to continue a line within a function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting your comma. It should be

```
something = mrfuntion(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, &
                  parameter4)
```

Comment: oops. that was a type in my example I gave. I've attached the actual error I am receiving from my compiler.

Comment: double oops. I had a residual argument left in there from a previous version of the function that I appeared to have been overlooking.